# url gets no data unless search button is pressed

Tags: python

I am trying webscraping with python.  The link "https://www.etnet.com.hk/www/eng/stocks/realtime/quote.php?code=00883" get no data unless the search button is pressed.  So, how to solve this for python webscraping?

I am trying to web scrape stock data via this link "https://www.etnet.com.hk/www/eng/stocks/realtime/quote.php?code=883" but failed as the url doesn't work.  The detailed data won't appear unless after I have manually press the search button.

Any idea how to fix it?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.etnet.com.hk/www/eng/stocks/realtime/quote.php?code=883"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
TRs = soup.findAll('tr')
print(TRs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the difference between working page headers (https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1SAN.png) and non-working one (https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XF5N.png). The first difference - you need to add a `Referer` to your requests. If still no results - check any other differences through the `Network` tab.

Comment: Thx but what I need is the detailed data as per circled https://drive.google.com/open?id=17_YYcCQ1CYPD3QPXZ7QWuWnxxLrLzDuX.  Any clues?

Comment: Sorry, I know what u mean.  I tried to add the referrer and it works.  Thankssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss